# Show the phone dialer with the number on the textblock when ever the textblock is clicked

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

[image: From the application]

// This is the code class, i want the numbers on the textblock to be connected to the phone dialer whenever i click the text block

```
public CenterDetails()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            pgr.IsActive = true;
        }
```

// This is the Navigated method

```
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            Rootobject myObject = (Rootobject)e.Parameter;
            HName.Text = myObject.centerName;
            HAddress.Text =myObject.address;
            HEmail.Text=myObject.email;
            HPhone.Text=myObject.phoneNO;
            pgr.IsActive=false;
        }
    }
```

//End

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are two ways in which you can connect a call using a give phone number :**

1.You can launch the default Phone Application with the give phone
    number and the user can choose whether to save it as a contact or
    call:*(Figure on left)*

```
private async void HyperlinkButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("tel: 8888888888"));
}
```

2.You can directly start a call with the specified name and phone
    number:*(Figure on Right)*

```
private async void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     PhoneCallStore phoneCallStore = await PhoneCallManager.RequestStoreAsync();

     Guid LineGuid = await phoneCallStore.GetDefaultLineAsync();

     PhoneLine phoneLine = await PhoneLine.FromIdAsync(LineGuid);
     phoneLine.Dial("+918888888888", "Some Name");
 }
```

---

**Screenshots for the above Code snippets:**

[image]   [image]

> Also, please make sure you add **Phone Call** Capability in you package
>   appxmanifest file.

**Edit:**

> You also need to add reference to the **Windows Mobile Extensions for
>   the UWP** in order to use *PhoneCallManager* and *PhoneLine*

Comment: According to the image above, i want the phone dialer to come out with the number on my textBlock whenever i tap the textBlock

Comment: PhoneCallManager and PhoneLine doesn't exist.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to add reference to **Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP**.. I have updated my answer with the same information.. Also, you cannot directly access the dialer with the phone number .. you can use the first method which basically does the same thing..

Comment: How will i access the dialer if not by phone number, i want user to click on the number and call with the phone dialer.

Comment: The application crashes when i used the first method

Comment: Are you sure your application crashes ? (and does not actually go into the background) because the URI "tel:" launches the default phone app of win 10.. Please add some debug info or exception Stack Trace..

Comment: I have done it and it works, but when trying to put it to windows store it was complaining that i enable the phone call in app manifest. i think some countries like china doesnt accept it. how will i exclude those countries in the target market

Comment: Please add a separate question for the excluding countries from the store listing, since it is not related to the original question. Also, please consider marking the current answer as accepted ..